# How to replace all the contents from one folder with another one

Tags: linux

I have folders `old` and `new`.

I want to replace all the contents in `old/*` to `new/*`. There can be many subdirectories in those folders.

But there can be few files which are not in `new/*` but are in `old/*`, so I want them to stay as they are.

How can I do that from a Linux shell?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

rsync would probably be a better option here. It's as simple as rsync -a subdir/ ./.
check this [unix.stackexchage answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/how-to-overwrite-target-files-with-mv) for better solutions

use  `-f` with the `cp` command

```
cp -fR /source/files /dest
```

suppress cp  to overwrite" prompt..

To override cp's alias you can simply enclose it in quotes:

```
 'cp' -rf ./source/* /destination/
```

for more information follow these links:

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/cp-command-problems-forcing-overwrite-using-cp-command-t5685.html

http://bytes.com/topic/unix/answers/865372-force-cp-overwrite-existing-directory

Comment: Don't use `rsync` for a one time copy, the overhead of hashing all dir contents is substantial, it only pays when keeping directories synchronized. For a gigantic one time copy, use a tarpipe.

Answer (score 26):

Use `rsync`. It will synchronize the directories in one direction. So, if you want to update your `old` folder with everything from `new`, but keep what's in there, just use:

```
rsync -avh --dry-run /path/to/new/ /path/to/old/
```

This will, in a first instance, just output the list of files that would be transferred. In that case: Everything found in `new` will be copied to `old`, unless it's already there. Everything in `old` stays as it is.

If it looks fine to you, remove the `--dry-run` argument to transmit them for real.

The `-avh` flags just enable archive mode (which will preserve timestamps, etc.), verbosity and human-readable file-sizes. Nothing will be deleted from the destination unless you specify the `--delete` flag. Consult `man rsync` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

please Try Once
if you want to change the name of a folder
theare are no command to rename the files/folders
the mv command is used to move the old directory to new directery
so rename sucess.

mkdir new
sudo mv -fr old/* new/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.